# How to display data from multiple table in list view asp.net MVC 5 or 6 using viewModel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

How can I achieve the same result using my view Model

```
Model 1:

public class Unit
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string UnitName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Staff> Staffs { get; set; }
}
```

Model 2:

```
public class Staff
{
    public int Id { get; set; }


    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public int UnitId { get; set; }
    public virtual Unit Unit { get; set; }
}
```

My ViewModel:

```
public class StaffVM
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public int UnitId { get; set; }
    public string UnitName { get; set; }
}
```

Controller Index function:

```
    // GET: Staffs
    public ActionResult Index()
    {

        var query = from c in db.MyStaff
                    join d in db.MyUnit on c.UnitId equals d.Id
                    select new StaffVM
                    {
                        Id = c.Id,
                        FullName = c.FullName,
                        UnitName = d.UnitName
                    };
        ViewBag.query = query;

        return View();

    }
```

My View Index view:

```
@model IEnumerable<MVC5WAuth.ViewModels.StaffVM>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
 }

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FullName)
        </th>
        <th>
           Unit
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in ViewBag.query) {
    <tr>
        <td>
           @item.FullName
       </td>
       <td>
           @item.UnitName
       </td>
       <td>
           @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.Id }) |
           @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.Id }) |
           @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.Id })
       </td>
   </tr>
}

</table>
```

Comment: Why use `ViewBag` and not `return View(query);`?

Comment: Hi Thanks @StephenMuecke you saved my day. cheers